# ARKit switch between ARWorldTrackingConfiguration and ARFaceTrackingConfiguration - Rear and Front Camera

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, arscnview

In my project I want to switch between `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` and `ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`.

I use two different types of view a `ARSCNView` to use the rear camera and a `ARView` to do the face tracking.
First I start the `ARSCNView` and after, if the user want, he can switch to face tracking

I start my view controller in this mode:

```
sceneView.delegate = self
sceneView.session.delegate = self

            // Set up scene content.
setupCamera()            
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(focusSquare)

let configurationBack  = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration(
configurationBack.isAutoFocusEnabled = true
configurationBack.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]


sceneView.session.run(configurationBack, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

And I load my Object (.scn)

When I want to switch to front camera I and pass to ARView I do this:

```
 let configurationFront  = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()

  // here I stop my ARSCNView session
  self.sceneView.session.pause()

    self.myArView = ARView.init(frame: self.sceneView.frame)

    self.myArView!.session.run(configurationFront)
    self.myArView!.session.delegate = self

    self.view.insertSubview(self.myArView!, aboveSubview: self.sceneView)
```

And than I load my `.rcproject`

So my problem begin here, when I try to return to back camera and pass to ARWorldTracking again.

This is my method:

```
// remove my ARView with face tracking
        self.myArView?.session.pause()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.myArView?.alpha = 0
        }) { (true) in
            self.myArView?.removeFromSuperview()
            self.myArView = nil

        }
// here I restart the initial ARSCNView
    let configurationBack  = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration(
        configurationBack.isAutoFocusEnabled = true
        configurationBack.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]


    session.run(configurationBack, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

When I switch to back camera, the sensor doesn't track the planes correctly.

How can I fix that, so how can I switch correctly between ARWorldTrackingConfiguration and ARFaceTrackingConfiguration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code seems OK. What do you mean that "the sensor doesn't track the planes correctly"? Can you explain the exact behavior?

Comment: @MoRezaFarahani For example, I place a focus square on horizontal and vertical planes to indicate at the user where the object will be placed, but It doesn't respect the surface. It "fly" in the middle of the screen

Comment: Do you need both horizontal and vertical detections at the same time?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work only after the app returns to use the back camera with ARSCNView @MoRezaFarahani

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to also remove all added nodes to the scene when you're pausing the session. Add below code after where you pause the session with `self.sceneView.session.pause()`:

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (childNode, _) in
    childNode.removeFromParentNode()
}
```